# how to get fixed base url independent of the server with the help of "<%=request.getContextPath()%>"

Tags: javascript

I have  used var URL = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>"; to get the base url. Its working fine in my local machine. But its not in any other server.please suggest me the solution

Answer (score 0):

javadocs :

> It is possible that a servlet container may match a context by more than one context path. In such cases this method will return the actual context path used by the request and it may differ from the path returned by the ServletContext.getContextPath() method. The context path returned by ServletContext.getContextPath() should be considered as the prime or preferred context path of the application.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/welcome";
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.